# Rendering a video from video editor

Tags: video, server-side-rendering, chunks

My current 1 minute video (with video+text+audio+images) takes over 6 min to render. I have been advised to do chunk rendering or parallel processing the frames and then use ffmpeg.

Current stack - typescript and nodejs.

Any suggestions